# What is the difference between a table variable and a local temporary table in OpenGauss?

Tags: sql, open-gauss

What is the difference between a table variable and a local temporary table in OpenGauss?

Answer (score 0):

A local temporary table is automatically dropped at the end of the current session. Therefore, you can create and use temporary tables in the current session as long as the connected database node in the session is normal. Temporary tables are created only in the current session. If a DDL statement involves operations on temporary tables, a DDL error will be generated. Therefore, you are not advised to perform operations on temporary tables in DDL statements.
You can refer to this link for more detailed information.
https://opengauss.org/en/docs/latest/docs/Developerguide/create-table.html